# Split based on _ and find the difference between dates

Tags: python, date, split

I am trying to find the difference between the below two dates. It is in the format of "dd-mm-yyyy". I splitted the two strings based on _ and extract the date, month and year.

```
previous_date = "filename_03_03_2021"
current_date = "filename_09_03_2021"
previous_array = previous_date.split("_")
```

Not sure after that what could be done to combine them into a date format and find the difference between dates in "days".

Any leads/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this in Python?

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Yes

Comment: Please mention your programming language in the question and also add the appropriate language tag. These two measures are your best chance to attract people who know to your question, so will greatly improve your chances of qualified answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could index into the list after split like `previous_array[1]` to get the values and add those to `date`

But tnstead of using split, you might use a pattern with 3 capture groups to make the match a bit more specific to get the numbers and then subtract the dates and get the days value.

You might make the date like pattern more specific using the pattern on [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html)

```
import re
from datetime import date

previous_date = "filename_03_03_2021"
current_date = "filename_09_03_2021"

pattern = r"filename_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{4})"

pMatch = re.match(pattern, previous_date)
cMatch = re.match(pattern, current_date)

pDate = date(int(pMatch.group(3)), int(pMatch.group(2)), int(pMatch.group(1)))
cDate = date(int(cMatch.group(3)), int(cMatch.group(2)), int(cMatch.group(1)))

print((cDate - pDate).days)
```

Output

```
6
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/tUhpzz)